Question regarding proof that a complex number lies on a line
This question is regarding the following problem,
If a complex number $z = x + iy$ satisfies the equation $Re(z+1) = |z-1|$, then prove that $z$ lies on $y^2 = 4x$
The proof for the above in my textbook is as follows
$$Re(x + iy + 1) = |x + iy - 1|$$
$$x + 1 = \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + y^2}$$
$$(x+1)^2 = (x-1)^2 + y^2$$
$$y^2 = 4x$$
My question is how does this prove that $z$ lies on the graph of $y^2 = 4x$, this is something that just happened to come after the simplification of the equation.
This is my issue, any help would be appreciated!

Lying on the graph of $y^2 = 4x$ is the same as satisfying the equation $y^2 = 4x$.

What you call a line is usually called a curve.

You may be confusing $z$ the coordinate variable and $z$ the complex variable. In this context $z=x+iy$ so we are only working on the complex plane: $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$. There is no third dimension that $z$ may represent.
The proof you presented shows that taking an arbirtary point $z=x+iy$ satisfying $Re(x+iy)=|x+iy|$, then it must be the case that $y^2=4x$. This is saying the point satisfies the condition $y^2=4x$ this means that the point lies on the curve $y^2=4x$.

If a point $a+ib$ lies on $y^2=4x$, that simply means $(a,b)$ as a point in the plane lies on the curve $y^2=4x$, which is the same as $b^2=4a$.
In this case, we showed that if $\mathfrak{R}(a+ib+1)=|a+ib-1|$ then $b^2=4a$ and that is enough.
Hope this helps. :)

The secret to determining of point, $z$ lines on a particular line if tantamount to asking if that point is collinear with any two points on that line. And the answer to that question shows up in the equation for the area of a triangle in the complex plane, which is written as
$$
A=\frac{i}{4}
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
z_1 & z_2 & z_3\\
z_1^* & z_2^* & z_3^*
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Clearly, then the condition for collinearity in the complex plane is if the area is equal to zero, or
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
z_1 & z_2 & z_3\\
z_1^* & z_2^* & z_3^*
\end{vmatrix}
=0
$$
Alternatively, the area can be expressed as
$$
A=\frac{1}{2}\text{Im}\{z_1 z_2^*\}
$$
where $z_1, z_2$ are vectors from the same point.
